# Python SVM confusing graph output

Tags: python, machine-learning

### Problem

I am attempting to build a one class SVM model for novelty detection. I am fairly new to ML and cannot seem to find a similar problem to the one I am having now. I have generated some random data, some to train, some to test and some with guaranteed outliers.

### CODE

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import array
from array import *
from sklearn import utils
from sklearn import svm 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager
from random import gauss
from random import seed
from random import random
from random import uniform

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
seed(42)

# generation common data
samples = 2000
ambient = 400
std_dev = 3
typical_chance = 0.001
abnormal_chance = 0.01
lower_bound = -100
upper_bound = 800

# Generate train data
i = 0;
X_train = array('f')
while i < samples:
   X_train.append(ambient+gauss(0,std_dev));
   r = random()
   if r < typical_chance:
       X_train[i] += uniform(lower_bound,upper_bound)
   i += 1

d = {'reading':X_train}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
X_train = np.array(df)
X_train.reshape(-1,1)

# Generate typical test data
i = 0;
X_typical_test = array('f')
while i < samples:
   X_typical_test.append(ambient+gauss(0,std_dev));
   r = random()
   if r < typical_chance:
       X_typical_test[i] += uniform(lower_bound,upper_bound)
   i += 1

dd = {'reading':X_typical_test}
ddf = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)
X_typical_test = np.array(ddf)
X_typical_test.reshape(-1,1)

# Generate abnormal test data
i = 0;
X_abnormal_test = array('f')
while i < samples:
   X_abnormal_test.append(ambient+gauss(0,3*std_dev));
   r = random()
   if r < abnormal_chance:
       X_abnormal_test[i] += uniform(lower_bound,upper_bound)
   i += 1

ddd = {'reading':X_abnormal_test}
dddf = pd.DataFrame(data=ddd)
X_abnormal_test = np.array(dddf)
X_abnormal_test.reshape(-1,1)

#model fit
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.001, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.001)
clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_train = y_pred_train.astype(np.float32)
y_pred_typical = clf.predict(X_typical_test)
y_pred_abnormal = clf.predict(X_abnormal_test)

# Generate noise to better see distribution of points
i = 0
while i < samples:
    y_pred_train[i] += gauss(0,0.125)
    i+=1
    
i = 0
while i < samples:
    y_pred_typical[i] += gauss(0,0.125)
    y_pred_abnormal[i] += gauss(0,0.125)
    i += 1

# plot the line, the samples, and the nearest vectors to the plane
plt.title("Trained SVM")
plt.scatter(X_train, y_pred_train,c='White',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(290,1210)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
plt.title("Trained SVM - narrowed")
plt.scatter(X_train, y_pred_train,c='White',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(350,450)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()

plt.title("Typical Test SVM")
plt.scatter(X_typical_test, y_pred_typical,c='green',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(290,1210)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
plt.title("Typical Test SVM - narrowed")
plt.scatter(X_typical_test, y_pred_typical,c='green',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(350,450)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()

plt.title("Abnormal Test SVM")
plt.scatter(X_abnormal_test, y_pred_abnormal,c='red',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(290,1210)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
plt.title("Abnormal Test SVM - narrowed")
plt.scatter(X_abnormal_test, y_pred_abnormal,c='red',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(350,450)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()

plt.title("Composite of Train, Typical Test, Abnormal Test SVM")
plt.scatter(X_train, y_pred_train,c='White',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.scatter(X_typical_test, y_pred_typical,c='green',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.scatter(X_abnormal_test, y_pred_abnormal,c='red',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(290,1210)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
plt.title("Composite - narrowed")
plt.scatter(X_train, y_pred_train,c='White',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.scatter(X_typical_test, y_pred_typical,c='green',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.scatter(X_abnormal_test, y_pred_abnormal,c='red',s=10, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(350,450)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

### Error

I would expect that oneClassSVM would label the points as a 1 or a -1. This has been my understanding. The first two scatter plots (Trained) do indeed plot the data points as a 1 or a -1. The remaining scatter plots on the other hand plot the data points as either a 1 or a 0, or in some cases a 1, a 0, and a -1. I am very confused as to why this is, as I understood SVM will group points into a 1 or a -1.

I really hope I have explained myself thoroughly enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: apologies, I believe I can remove the histograms as they probably aren't relevant, but I thought it best to leave the code for the actual plots in as that is where my issue seems to lie.

Comment: Probably better fit for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/